# React - Dynamic Routing with JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, react-router

How do I dynamically route JSON in React?

Say the JSON is the code below:

```
[{  "id": 1,
    "fullName": "Jenny Chan",
    "address": "3 waterfoot road",
    "phoneNumber": "333-962-7516",
    "email": "jenny.chan@email.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "fullName": "Jessica warren",
    "address": "4 tall town",
    "phoneNumber": "011-211-7516",
    "email": "jessica.warren@email.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "fullName": "Tony Frank",
    "address": "11 lesly road",
    "phoneNumber": "788-962-7516",
    "email": "tony.frank@email.com"
  },]
```

And in my table I have the three emails.

```
jenny.chan@email.com 
jessica.warren@email.com 
tony.frank@email.com
```

When I click on these emails I would like for them to dynamically route to each page.
How do I do this and then pass through the emails as destructured props so I can access the email information please???

Thanks

Comment: where do you want it to route to when clicked? open the email client like gmail?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Read this [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information to help people understand your problem.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry I am new,

when I click I want to route to something like: 

"/user:id"
and I want to be able to access the email information please

Comment: What does to route mean? Give some details for what you want to get and edit the question. Then users could answer better.

Comment: your question is not understandable.